# Erro ao enviar imagem para o imgur, como resolver?

Tags: java, imgur

Estou tentando enviar uma imagem para o Imgur mas está dando erro, não me lembro como faço para pegar a imagem. Estou usando este código:

```
     public static String getImgurContent() throws Exception {
        URL url;
        url = new URL("https://api.imgur.com/3/image");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("image", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(IMAGEM_AQUI, "UTF-8");

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Client-ID " + "000000000");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        conn.connect();
        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            stb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();

        return stb.toString();
    }
```

Bom, tem esse `IMAGEM_AQUI`, quando eu coloco um *link* de uma imagem tipo `http://i.imgur.com/38KP393.png` funciona normalmente. Mas eu queria saber como faço para pegar uma imagem do meu projeto ou um objeto do tipo `Image` ou `BufferedImage` quando tento colocar só o nome tipo `"imagem.png"` ele não funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando precisei implementar um método para o envio de imagens ao Imgur (da forma que você está fazendo, sem autenticação) acabei encontrando o mesmo código que está utilizando (Exemplo sobre a API v2). Tentei usá-lo em minha aplicação mas não consegui, acabei criando um método diferente, se não tiver problema para você depender de outras bibliotecas segue uma sugestão:

```
public class Imgur { 
    private final String ENDPOINT  = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload/json";
    private final String CLIENT_ID = "sua_client_id";

    public String upload(Path path){
        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entityBuilder.addPart("image", new FileBody(path.toFile()));

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ENDPOINT);
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID "+ CLIENT_ID);
        httpPost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

        CloseableHttpClient closeable = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRoutePlanner(new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(ProxySelector.getDefault())).build();

        String responseString = null; 
        try {

            HttpResponse response = closeable.execute(httpPost);
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        } catch(IOException | ParseException e){
            /* Tratamento ... */
        }
        return responseString;
    }
}
```

O interessante é que desse modo você não precisa se preocupar com a manipulação do arquivo, isto é, criar um `BufferedImage`, escrever a imagem (onde é necessário obter a extensão correta do arquivo), converter para `Base64`, etc. Criando um objeto `FileBody` todas essas questões são resolvidas com uma linha de código: `new FileBody(path.toFile())`.

A parte importante: o método retornará uma string contendo o JSON de resposta. Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca de sua preferência para tratar esse retorno para filtrar e manipular o conteúdo.

```
// Faz o envio do arquivo e retorna a String contendo o JSON de resposta.
String response = upload(Paths.get("C:\\imagem.png"));  

// Obtém somente as informações sobre a foto enviada (o que realmente importa).
JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(response).get("data");

// Monta os links...
String imageLink = responseJson.get("link");
String deleteUrl = "http://www.imgur.com/delete/" + responseJson.get("deletehash");
```

---

- [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/).